# Furniture layout, disagreement with officemate

Tags: conflict, office-layout, workplace-rhythm

I am in problem. A month before I got job, I was allocated an office. It is a shared office for 3 persons. Everyone is assigned with a table and cupbourd. After a month I changed some setting in office only in my portion, just exchanged my cupboard with table in setting. One of my colleague changed the whole setting in my absence. I asked why? She said "why you didn't ask to me?" Alongwith this she offered me to take her place. I was not agreeing on thes. And she was saying again and again that "would you like to exchange setting with me"? My mind was fully confused and I took decision to change the place with her. Which is I think a big mistake. After exchanging place she threatened me that she will complain against me in a very harsh way if I changed anything again. Now I amon her previous place. Now I am so much worried abou her threatning? Please suggest me what should I do to get my place back because I was threatened for this place.
Plus tell me where I did anything wrong in all this according to your point of view?

Comment: So, do I understand this right? You are now sitting at her previous deske and she wants to complain if you change anything at this desk?

Comment: Yes. She talked like it was a fighting, And now I am regreting that why I changed the place. Please tell me how I can get my place back?

Comment: Have you spoken to your boss?

Comment: Yes all the staff is with me as everyone is angry with her. But she is favourite to our boss. So he didn't give me any response. Thats why I want to get my place back.

Comment: Why is it important to get your old desk back? Was there something special about it, or something unpleasant about your current one, or is it simply the feeling that she took advantage of you?

Comment: No it is the way she was threatning to me. From the day the place changed I didn't sit on her previous desk. Because of the feeling of being threatened.

Comment: I am worrried that she will do something in revenge because I have told boss about all this.

Comment: Would it be a good thing to ask for my place back to some higher person in the department? Would it have a negative impact on my reputation?

Comment: @kilis according to you it was my fault? And can you please explain your answer it is not clear to me?

Comment: I am requesting to everyone please guide me because I am new to office. If I am wrong then clearly say it where I was wrong? If asking my place back is wrong then clearify it. Please guide.

Comment: @kilis Perhaps English isn't their mother tongue nor the official language of the country they work in. Even so, none of us are entirely aware of OP's circumstances. If they were in an English speaking country, they might be learning the language, which neither their manager nor any of their colleagues have a problem with, so why should we? I find the comment condescending and unhelpful when the OP is obviously very worried. Perhaps English is their first language but due to hire worried they are they are not bothered with the spelling.

Comment: Everyone is devoting my question no one is reponding positively. I am asking for guidance which is not provided.

Comment: Anything here is possible, from someone bullying the OP to the OP just changing things without taking care of the needs of their fellow office mates. However, I give OP the benefit of doubt. One possibility to respond to the colleague is: "There is no need to talk in this way to me, I must ask you not to take this tone with me again. Of course, if we have a disagreement about the setting of the office, then let's sit together and talk about how to find a solution that everyone can live with. Let me know when you would like to discuss possible arrangements."

Comment: Perhaps you should have asked some superiors, depending on the structure of your department. Is she one on them or who is she to require you to ask specifically her to change something?

Comment: @Kilisi: This is very condescending and unnessesary. Also, the connection between the OP:s spelling and office work is not clear.

Comment: @puck no she is appointed with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I understand it:

- you moved the furniture around
- your colleague moved some furniture around, and this seems to have been the point at which conflict started
- your colleague persuaded you to swap places
- your colleague now threatens to make trouble for you if you move the furniture again.

And you have two motivations:

- to get your old place back
- to avoid further conflict with the colleague

The problem is your two motivations are contradictory. Insisting on a move back or moving stuff again will certainly reignite the conflict, and you already know your boss views your colleague more favourably. This is where it is difficult for us to advise you, as we cannot tell how important these are to you. If being in a different place is just an irritation because you feel your colleague has cheated you, you need to ask if this is really worth the risk of reopening the conflict and dragging your boss into it. At the other extreme, if the new desk is physically problematic for you to the point where it harms your work, you absolutely should raise it. You need to judge that for yourself.

Comment: Okay your answer is satisfactory. But now everything has passed. But I don't know why I have feelings of discomfort. I am not happy in this place. It is good, it is in corner. No one can interfare in my work as before I was being disturbed by others. But I am unable to explain my condition. What is this feeling.

Comment: Is it wrong to exchange my place with her? Or the decision taken in conflict is always a regret?

Comment: No, if you're less disturbed in the new spot and your colleague also got what she wanted then it was probably a good decision, even if the circumstances weren't good. I guess part of your unease is that, having seen your colleague make a big deal out of a very minor issue, it's soured the atmosphere in your little office - and you anticipate a repeat.

Comment: Okay. But now my boss and other senior person's behavior is changed. They are like they want to avoid me. I felt rudeness in their replies. What should I do now. I am completely stuck in this. I am afraid they will eliminate me from office.

Comment: I am unable to understand that where I am wrong in all this?

Comment: @saintjoseph Office politics can be quite tricky especially when you are _'new'_. I'd suggest you don't take your subjective observations too serious and give you and others a little bit of time until the dust of the previous _'incident'_ has settled. Try to be friendly and polite as always - but don't let it get to you if one or two of your co-workers are avoiding you..

Comment: Thankyou all for your valueable suggestions.